# match in columns with R

Tags: r, for-loop, match

I have data in a matrix in the following way:

```
label     1        2      3       4
id_101   10       30      43      32
id_102    3       32     43       43
id_111    45      34     22       66
id_201    87      65     66       34
id_202    45      76     76       44
......
```

this data has been transformed in a list so it is like:

```
[[1]]
     [1]  label   1     2       
     [3]      3   4
[[2]]
     [1]  id_101 .....

 ......
```

what I want is to know if a value **a** matches one of the values from the column named **label**. For that purpose I am using a for loop with the match instruction:

```
    a<-"id_201"    ///for example
for (pos in 2:length(matrix))
{

    if (!is.na(match(a,tabd[[pos]][[1]])))
    {
        found<-1
        print(found)
        break
    }
}
    if (found) print(pos)
```

I was wondering if there is an efficient way to look if the value from the variable **a**  matches any value of the column under **label** and to get its position, but without using the for loop.
Thanks

Comment: `lapply(tabd, '[', 1)` will give you the value of the first element in each list.  `unlist(lapply(tabd, '[', 1)) == a` gives a boolean vector  where there are matches.  However, I think your initial transformation step could be improved since it looks like data is in columns 2:5 while the first column is a label...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a list somewhat like what you describe, although it prints with surounding double quotes. Working with it suggests this should work

```
which( sapply(txtList, "[", 1) == a )
```